# Lost my extensions for Cinnamon by accidentally upgrading to 2.4.5 any easy fix?

Tags: ppa, cinnamon, downgrade

So I'm running 14.04 and using Cinnamon I loved it until somehow an apt-get upgrade or something caused Cinnamon to crash every time it loaded. I did a dist-upgrade which removed Cinnamon. Then I re-installed it, but now it seems I have 2.4.5 which is kinda buggy and doesn't work with many extensions. I'm using the letscape PPA for presumably stable builds. Is there any way that I can revert to cinnamon 2.4? Should I use a different PPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is not way to revert the change. There are not an backup to the packages on https://launchpad.net/. As i know there are not any repository for cinnamon 2.2 on ubnutu 14.04 right now. The only way is find the old packages if they are on /var/cache/apt/archives and try to install it locally. As an alternative you can use ubuntu 14.10 or Debian, that right now use Cinnamon 2.2.

You can ask how to fix the not working extensions. Some of them can be easy fixed. I can try to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll try checking locally, but fixing the extensions would be preferable yes? The thing is I don't know how to find out what about CinnaDockPlus is causing incompatibility with this current release of Cinnamon.

Comment: Ok, if you don't have a memory problem like me will be preferable. I really don't use my own repository, but on the last cinnamon unstable the extension is working. Just you need to open the file ~/.local/share/cinnamon/extensions/CinnaDock Plus@entelechy/metadata.json and add the 2.4 version(on cinnamon-version). This could be used for all cinnamon extensions. Take care.